# Utility for releasing packages to PyPi?

Tags: python, packaging, pip, pypi

I have a number of python packages in GitHub repositories and it would be really great to have these available in PyPi. I know I could do these releases manually (update the version number, perhaps update a changelog, tag the release in GitHub, get the download url from GitHub, update PyPi with the release etc.) but I keep thinking that there must be a script/utility somewhere to make this a single-command process.

I am not massively familiar with the python packaging process, so perhaps I am coming at this from the wrong angle. I just don't think I can be the first one to have the idea of making this whole process a lot easier.

**Edit:** As there seems to be some confusion about what I am asking for: *Are there any tools that make releasing Python packages to PyPi a faster and more streamlined process?*

I have tried searching around but have yet to find anything.

Comment: Yes.  `setup.py` handles most of this.  What part of the standard documentation is confusing?  http://docs.python.org/distutils/uploading.html  seems clear.  Can you be **specific** on what part of this is confusing?

Comment: I have been reading through the docs and I can see `setup.py` does handle a lot of this, but it seems that there are a number of common steps that `setup.py` doesn't cover (eg: version bump, updating the change log). I just thought that, as this is such a common process, that there may be a utility for wrapping everything up in one command (e.g. updating the package's version, pulling changelog from git, then pushing changes back and updating PyPi).

Comment: Please **update** the question to explain **precisely** what you need that's not in the documentation.  If all you're doing is automating some GitHub activities, then (1) search for related questions and (2) **update** this question to explain how none of the other questions are appropriate.

Comment: "faster and more streamlined process" isn't really very specific, is it?  What's not fast enough?  What steps need to be improved?  Can you revise the question to explain what **specific** steps bother you?  We don't know what seems slow or unstreamlined to you.

Comment: This was a deliberately general question trying to seek advice (rather than a specific solution) from the Python community. I did not have a specific problem, only the overall concern I illustrated in my question. I had assumed that it would be ok for me to ask such a question but I am sorry if you feel I have wasted your time.

Comment: "if you feel I have wasted your time". Please do not project feelings onto other people. What I "feel" isn't relevant.  Please simply explain your question for those of us who are confused.  If you want help, you should **explain** what problem you're having.  "faster and more streamlined process".  If you can't explain what's slow or unstreamlined, then we can't know what difficulty you're having.  If we don't understand your difficulty, we can't explain what to do differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I really don't know if anyone else has had this problem/concern, but I had an itch I needed to scratch so I have made this:

http://seed.readthedocs.org

I wouldn't be surprised if there is something out there already that does this better, but for now this is what I'll use :)

Comment: Well, 5 years late I'm still using it!

Answer (score 0):

There is [changes](https://github.com/michaeljoseph/changes), software that makes the pypi publish just a single step. Looks like that is quite similar to [seed](http://seed.readthedocs.org).

Anyway, it would be nice if pypi could just check if on github there is a new tagged release and release it on pypi.